# Python package callable from the shell?

Tags: python, shell, package, pypi

I have a tool written in Python which I would like to turn into a Python package, to make it easier to install dependencies and distribute it.

There are two usages:

1. you import the module `mytool.py`, call the wrapper function on it, a summary of some measurements is printed on screen and you obtain a dictionary with the full results. `import mytool; results = mytool.mytool(param1=1, param2=2)`
2. You call `mytool.py` from a shell, with the same parameters as above and a summary of the measurements is printed on screen. `$ python mytool.py --param1 1 --param2 2`

Would this be correct?
I understand that when you install a package from `pypi`, the main usage is the one in point 1. Once installed, It could be cumbersome to go find the exact path to `mytool.py`, and call it from the shell. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I think is fine, just make sure in your setup.py you specify a nice path to store the script playing a bit with the disutils lib

```
from distutils import setup
setup(
    ...,
    scripts=['path/to/your/script',],
    ...
)
```

Some nice info can be found here https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/index.html#distutils-index

https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/packageindex.html

Comment: I just read the page on the first link and I didn't understand the purpose (or rather, the effect!) of specifying the path to the script in scripts=[...]. What's the effect on the user?

Comment: disutil has a specific way to package scripts callable from shell which is what you need https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts
"Scripts are files containing Python source code, intended to be started from the command line. Scripts don’t require Distutils to do anything very complicated."

Comment: Yup. So does it get automatically installed as a shell command too and then used like `$ mytool --param1 1 --param2 2` ?

Comment: The script should be copied to your PATH and be available if the package was properly done, check this http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/command-line-scripts.html, besides adding it to scripts list inside your script make sure you define #!/usr/bin/env python at the beginning replacing it with your python enviorment

Comment: Just as a side note: you may want to split `mytool.py` in two:  a 'non-executable' Python module for the first use case, and a wrapper script (importing and using the module) for the second use case. It makes things clearer and also allow the Python interpreter to make use of pre-compiled bytecode (.pyc file) for the module itself (scripts - that is, Python source file directly passed to the interpreter - are always recompiled).